# Ubuntu, or Fedora?

Tags: 14.10, fedora

I've been using Fedora now for the past 2 months, and, well, I used to use Ubuntu, but slowly moved away from it as I thought it was only for those just starting out with Linux, and about all the privacy concerns involved with the OS.

So, my question is this: Should I move back to Ubuntu? Ecspically with all the latest hype about the phones, tablets, and such, maybe it might be a good thing to do? And, if that's the case, what version should I choose? The 14.04.1, or the 14.10?

Comment: This is an opinion, not a real question. Use the OS that fits you ;)

Comment: Your asking a bunch of (mostly) Ubuntu users the question, so you will likely get a biased answer. Fedora has newer stuff and newer features, whilst Ubuntu is more user friendly, and sometimes more supported software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation? Definite go back to ubuntu. for these reasons.

1. debian system added extra level of protection,(sudo.....) to prevent novice users from tempering the OS's file system, while in administrative mode. You have to give an explicit command for wanting to change setting.
2. As the largest distribution, ubuntu keeps its OS fresh with twice-a-year upgrades. Some people find it arduous, and pron to unexpected problems. Others find it refreshing.
   You always have the choice to disable the auto-upgrade,and do so whenever you chose to.
3. Ubuntu has the largest fan based users, and as you see on this forum, the largest repository of answers to your question.

As for which one (14.10 vs. 14.04), the latter one is classified as Long Term System (LTS) which means, it is bug free. The first is not, and constantly upgraded. So if you do install the 14.10, make sure to check for update & Upgrades frequently.

Comment: The first point Fedora does anyway, if anything better than Ubuntu, and the second Fedora is currently set to be [released twice a year](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle) ; the third is true though